# Regex for find and replace

Tags: regex, replace

I want to find and replace all Exceptions in my project and I need a regex for that.An exceptions is like this: Exception(' some text that contains letters,numbers,'!','space',',' ');

Comment: So you mean to say, You want to replace the above characters with some regex ?

Comment: Can you give some examples of matching and non-matching text and what you've tried?

Comment: example matching: Exception('we are sorry for the inconvenience!') example non-matching Exception($variable);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this will get them:

```
Exception\(\'[\s\S]*?\'\);
```

EDIT:

For Exception(quotes) only:

```
Exception\(\'[\s\S]*?\'\);
```

EDIT 2:

For substituting the contents of Exception quotes, use this Regex:

```
(Exception\()('[\s\S]*?')(\);)
```

On the "Find" field. To match that exception and capture the parts that you want to keep, and then use this to substitute:

```
$1\$this->translate\($2\)$3
```

on the "Replace with" field.

$1/$2 is 1st/2nd Group captured by ()

Comment: Tyress your solution worked but I want to be sure that between () is a string,because right now it also return Exception(variable) so i need something like this Exception('regex');

Comment: Good to hear. Added a with-quotes only version

Comment: Thanks is works great.I am gona give you the corect answer and I have one more question if you don't mind I want to find and replace those result for Exception('text') with Exception($this->translate('text')) any idea what to write in the replace box?

Comment: Ahh...well, you're going to have to group the items that you need and replace them

Comment: Sorry but I am not so sure how to use the second part.Can you please tell me what to put exactly in find field and what to put in replace?

Comment: is worked but I haven't used $1/$2 is 1st/2nd Group captured by () because I didn't know what you mean by capture and substitue.I put in the find field (Exception\()('[\s\S]*?')(\);) in the substitute field $1\$this->translate\($2\)$3 and it seems to work.

Comment: I hope is alright this way to,probably he capture them that way already or something like that,can't realy explain.

Comment: @SerbanAlexandru just trying to explain what $1 and $2 means. That line does nothing. Glad it worked

Comment: O I get it know,I understand what they means but also taught that I have to put it somewhere.Thanks again!